# cout fail when used cin after redirect console stream

Tags: c++

I want to redirect console streams to cin, cout and cerr. (its a GUI application)
Well, I have written this class which do this but when use cin, cout works no more.

GetLastError says me INVALID_HANDLE VALUE

Can you explain me how fix this?

```
Kconsole.h
class Kconsole
{

    public:
    
        Kconsole();
        ~Kconsole();                

        void CreateConsole( void );
        void CloseConsole ( void );

    private:


        HANDLE hin;
        HANDLE hout;
        HWND hwnd;
        
        bool closed;
        bool err;       
            
        ofstream n_cout;
        ofstream n_cerr; // new streams
        ifstream n_cin;

        streambuf* old_cout;
        streambuf* old_cerr; // old streams
        streambuf* old_cin;

};
```

Class method:

```
void Kconsole::CreateConsole( void ){

// create a console window
int ok = AllocConsole();

if ( ok == 0 ) // check console creation
{
    
    this->err = true;
    return;        
}    

// redirect cout to console window
this->old_cout = cout.rdbuf();    
this->n_cout.open("CONOUT$");    
cout.rdbuf( this->n_cout.rdbuf() );

// redirect cerr
this->old_cerr = cerr.rdbuf();
this->n_cerr.open("CONOUT$");
cerr.rdbuf( this->n_cerr.rdbuf() );

// redirect cin
this->old_cin = cin.rdbuf();
this->n_cin.open("CONIN$");
cin.rdbuf( this->n_cin.rdbuf() );

//// set title
SetConsoleTitle("Console");
this->hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
//
//// get handles
this->hin = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);    
this->hout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
return;}
```

Main function

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,intnCmdShow){

 // All application initialization as RegisterClass, CreateWindow...

// CreateConsole Call

cout << "\nTest string"; // ok, writes this in opened console

int n = 0;

cin >> n; // ok, get typed number
n++;

cout << "\n test finished"; // dont outputs nothing to console

// here GetLastError says INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

cerr << "\n testing cerr" // cerr outputs in console " test finished" and "testing cerr"
}
```

Comment: What are the `n_cout` etc objects you're using? What class are you using for the streambuffers? It seems slightly odd that you're getting a streambuffer from a preexisting stream.

Comment: Try just creating three `filebuf` objects without `fstream` around them. Then there's no possible confusion about ownership semantics inside the implementation.

Comment: I don't understand you. I don't see any confusion in code. Please, explain this.

Comment: @krnl: <- use the "@" sign and my name so I'm notified of your reply ;v)

Comment: It looks like you're creating `fstream` objects and only using the `filebuf` inside via `rdbuf()`. It would be more straightforward to just instantiate `filebuf` instead of `fstream`. I'm concerned that this way of doing things may confuse your iostreams implementation, and in any case, it's somewhat roundabout.

Comment: However, I don't think it's really likely enough to solve the problem that I would put it in an answer :vP

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you're messing with `std::cout` et al at all. If you redirect `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin` to the console you can then call `std::ios::sync_with_stdio()` to make sure `std::cout`, `std::cerr` and `std::cin` all work. E.g:

```
// redirect unbuffered STDIN to the console
intptr_t lStdHandle = (intptr_t)GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
int hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
FILE *fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "r" );
*stdin = *fp;
setvbuf( stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

std::ios::sync_with_stdio();
```

Here's a great article (with source) that [explains](http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm) it all.

Comment: If you don't understand the code then please don't bother. First of all GetStdHandle() does *not* return a pointer, it returns a handle. Casting a pointer to long is also perfectly reasonable and possible, you just have to know what you are doing and that it's safe to do so, e.g. on an x86 32-bit platform, it's perfectly ok. In this case the code was quoted from the article I mentioned which was written in 1997 so 64-bit consideration were not common back then. I didn't expect nitpicking to this degree, but thanks for reminding me why I stopped answering questions at SO.

Comment: Personally I try to view upvotes/downvotes in relation to the question and this is the second time in two days I've been downvoted by some small thing that's completely unrelated to the original question. I don't consider my response "not useful" in regards to the original question. Anyway thanks for letting me know why I was downvoted but I would personally just settle for a comment if I was just nitpicking on an otherwise useful answer. I would fix my answer just the same.

Comment: Except that in 2010, you have to seriously consider the possibility that sizeof(long) != sizeof(void*), which HANDLE is typedefed as. It's certainly true that casting is not always unsafe, but, it certainly is not always safe and not a habit you should get into. Besides, since you removed the bad code, I see no reason not to change my downvote.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `cin` and `cout` are initially aliased to `stdin` and `stdout`, not to the console. If you redirect to something else (even if it is the console) then `sync_with_stdio` has no effect. In any case, the feature is enabled by default, so simply calling `sync_with_stdio()` at initialization is guaranteed to have no effect.

Comment: The fact is that the code *is* redirecting `cin`/`cout`/`cerr` to stdio. Instead of just trying to change `cout`, `cerr` and `cin`, this solution also changes `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin`. By first redirecting stdio to the console, the `sync_with_stdio()` is there as a safe guard I guess (without looking it up I assumed it was of greater importance). I'm not the original author of the article. I posted some code from it to give an idea of it to those too lazy to click on a link. This "kindness" has caused me no end of grief and I will henceforth only post code I have written myself.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're opening the same file twice with `fstream`.

```
this->old_cout = cout.rdbuf();    
this->n_cout.open("CONOUT$");    // open for writing #1
cout.rdbuf( this->n_cout.rdbuf() );

// redirect cerr
this->old_cerr = cerr.rdbuf();
this->n_cerr.open("CONOUT$");    // open for writing #2
cerr.rdbuf( this->n_cerr.rdbuf() );
```

Even if your OS supports this, now there are two separate I/O buffers trying to control the file. If you try to use both, it will result in garbled output.

Either send `cout` and `cerr` to different files, or use the same `filebuf` for both.

```
this->old_cout = cout.rdbuf();    
this->n_cout.open("CONOUT$");    
cout.rdbuf( this->n_cout.rdbuf() );

// redirect cerr
this->old_cerr = cerr.rdbuf();
cerr.rdbuf( this->n_cout.rdbuf() ); // same filebuf
```

I think this is still a little wonky, but it should be supported by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make your app a console app? You can still create windows from a console app, but it means there will always be a console, and always be standard input and output streams.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is after use cin, cout handle is closed or released.
GetLastError says code 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE)

I have tried open CONOUT$ once as you say, tried open CONERR$ instead CONOUT$ twice, perhaps close CONOUT$ handle manually via CloseHandle and Open it again with GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) or CreateFile.

In all cases, cout don't print anything. Only when use cerr all content remaining is written.